# How can I exit while loop if a non Int value is entered?

Tags: java, while-loop

How do can I exit a loop if a non **int** value is entered?

Should I do this in the main class?

```
package testing;

//importing java scanner
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Testing {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //importing scanner for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //variable for how many positions to shift indexes in array
    int shift;

    //Object for Shifter, passing 20 as parameter
    Shifter numbers = new Shifter(20);

    //Call Display method
    numbers.display();

    //how many positions to shift
    System.out.print("\nYou want to shift how many positions? ");

    //Assigning user input to shift variable
    shift = input.nextLine();

    numbers.shift();
}
```

Now the Shift Class:

```
package Testing;
import java.util.*;

public class Shifter 
{
private int numbers[]; 

Shifter(int totalSize) 
{   

    int index = 1;  

     numbers = new int[totalSize];            

    //Loop for assigning values to array indexes
    for(int i= 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {   
        data[i]= firstIndex;
        firstIndex++;
    }

}

public void shift(int position) 
{   
    //method variable assigned value of pos parameter
    int shiftNum = position;     
    //Array to hold new arrangement of elements
    int dataHolder[] = new int[numbers.length];

    **//I want to put a while loop here that will exit the loop when a letter is entered**
    **//I tried using .isNaN but can't get it to work

    while()
    {

    if(shiftNum > 0)
        {


         }

    }

}
```

Comment: You know ofcource that in your code you never pass the `input` to `Shifter`.

Comment: Yes, I actually have it as shift = input.nextInt(); I was copyying and pasting, I tried to edit post but it won't let  me

Comment: `shift` is just a `string`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
while (...) {
    String inputString = "..";
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(inputString);   // try to parse the input string as an integer
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        break;     // not an integer, exiting loop
    }
}
```

Or you may also be interested in [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29):

```
while (...) {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = input.nextInt();
    } else {
        break;     // not an integer, exiting loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Serves the purpose, but better to avoid a logic based on NumberFormatException

Answer (score -1):

Is the code working? As per the specifications [Scanner.nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) returns a string.

So, if you change it to `shift = input.nextInt();`. That should serve the purpose